# Path paramater in generated page for Swagger UI does not show available values

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm using a yaml file to automatically generate the Swagger report for our web service.  It basically boils down to this:

```
resourcePackages:
  - com.employee.api.service
openAPI:
  info:
    version: 0.1
    title: Employee Service
    description: Shows services for employees
  servers:
    - url: http://test.internal.com:5000/employees
      description: Test Server
```

This generates a page based of the endpoints for each java class in the `service` package.  A seperate service uses swagger-ui-react to read the resulting openapi.json and render a webpage for it.  We are using Swagger version 3.

In each endpoint, we have a path param, `parameter`, that is not replaced by its values in the generated report.  The java code itself is:

```
@Path("/{parameter: api|internal}/jobs")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class EmployeeJobsResource{

    private EmployeeJobsManager employeeJobsManager;
    public EmployeeJobsResource(EmployeeJobsManager employeeJobsManager) {
        this.employeeJobsManager = employeeJobsManager;
    }

    @GET
    @Timed
    public Response getAllAvailablePositions(@QueryParam("departmentName") String departmentName, @QueryParam("country") String country, @QueryParam("ids") String ids) {
    ...
    }
```

In the Swagger output, we can see that the query parameters are defined under each method, and even have dropdowns and text boxes for these parameters.  However, the path parameter where `api` or `internal` are set does not have any definition in the UI; indeed, it is represented as:

```
{parameter}/jobs
```

Is there any way, in either the openapi.yaml file or in the java code itself, that I can automatically replace the parameter with `api`?  I know that I can set individual paths in the yaml file, but I have around 40 endpoints with this setup; that would make maintenance an issue later on.

Comment: What library/tool do you use to generate the OpenAPI file from Java code - Springfox or something else? Are you sure `@Path("/{parameter: api|internal}/jobs")` is the correct annotation? Maybe you need something like `@Parameter(..., schema=@Schema(..., allowableValues =  {"api", "internal"}))` (see [@Parameter](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#parameter)).

Comment: We use swagger-jaxrs2 from io.swagger.core.v3 to generate the code.  `@Path` is annotation from javax.ws.rs, from before we integrated OpenAPI.  I assume `@Parameter` is the replacement, so let me try using that instead.